# RecyclerView.notifyItemChanged() does nothing when ItemAnimator is null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

I've found that calls to `RecyclerView.notifyItemChanged()` do not update the UI (like they should be) when I have removed the item animator via `RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)`. If I don't remove the item animator everything is fine.

Has anyone dealt with this behaviour before? Is it a bug, or are there subtle details here that I am missing?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Isn't that you just don't see any indication of the UI being updated? Because if you remove the item animator, there won't be any difference (or visual change) unless the view binding process goes differently than before...

Comment: Have something similar. If I add a DefaultItemAnimator that that returns false on animateChange then the UI isn't correctly updated.
I have a button that I make visible if a certain conditon is met in onBind - and it never shows. I can click it though - really weird stuff...